# Use ComboBox to restrict the columns in a query in access DB

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

I Have a Query that each field represents a date, so I was wondering If two combo box with a button could show  a default view like resource, gender, ETC, And all the fields between the two combo box like `Apr_1` to `Apr_15`

**NOTE** I'm using  Access 2010

Comment: You should really elaborate on your problem some more it's difficult to understand what you are asking, plus you have a tag for mysql when you are asking a question about access.

Comment: Sorry about that, what I'm asking for is that I need two combo box to show an specific field that is on that query, per say one of the combo says Apr_1 and there is a column heading called Apr_1 and in the other combo box says Apr_15 and there is a column name Apr_15, so I want to show Apr_1, Apr_2,... up to Apr_15, basically the columns are like "dates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of weeks finally solved it using dynamic SQL statement if anyone is interest in this method please let me know